# D3jS color scales do not work

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hello I am trying to add color fill to my bar chart which has a linear scale. The code which I am trying somehow wont work. could you please let me know what I am doing wrong. sorry, I am pretty new to D3jS and JavaScript.

Thanks!

```
<script>
        var data = [{ "MonthYearShortName": "2014-09-13T00:00:00", "Product": "Deposits", "Actual": 330393232.5, "Forecast": 495589848.75, "Target": 495589848.75 }, { "MonthYearShortName": "2014-09-13T00:00:00", "Product": "Fee Based", "Actual": 111868709.42, "Forecast": 167803064.13, "Target": 167803064.13 }, { "MonthYearShortName": "2014-09-13T00:00:00", "Product": "Lending", "Actual": 18146873.33, "Forecast": 27220309.995, "Target": 27220309.995 }];

        var color = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain(0, function (d) { return max(d.Actual); })
            .range(["#f3c40e", "#7d6507"]);

        var width = 420,
            barHeight = 20;

        var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
            .range([0, width]);

        var chart = d3.select('#ReportContent_ReportContent svg')
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

        var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
          .data(data, function (d) { return d.Actual; })
          .enter().append("g")
           .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

        bar.append("rect")
            .attr("width", function (d) { return d.Actual / 1000000; })
            .attr("height", function (d) { return d.Actual / 10000000;})
            .attr("fill", color);

        bar.append("text")
            .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.Actual) - 3; })
            .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function (d) { return d.Product; });
    </script>
```

Comment: There is no (x, y) position for a bar. And domain could be something like `[0, Math.max.apply(Math,data.map(function(o){return o.Actual;}))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more issues with this bar chart than the color code, and even that one fix needs a bit more adjustment. The easiest thing was to work on a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bPd5B/) rather than try to squeeze all changes in a comment.

```
bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", function (d) { return x(d.Actual); }) //change
    .attr("height", barHeight) //change
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.Actual);} ); //change
```

There are still other changes...the domain setting was not quite right, and I also added a margin so that the text displays right using a text-anchor.

In any case, overall, I think this will take you closer to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass a function to `attr('fill, )`, not just a scale.

```
    bar.append("rect")
        .attr("width", function (d) { return d.Actual / 1000000; })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return d.Actual / 10000000;})
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d); );
```

It also seems like your scale is not set up properly:

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(0, THIS NEEDS TO BE A VALUE)
        .range(["#f3c40e", "#7d6507"]);
```

The second part of the `domain` needs to be a value (or a function that evaluates to one)

Comment: Thanks @chopper. The statement makes sense now. Though I am still not getting anything appended under the SVG tags. Should I change the domain, is there something wrong with it? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you need to change the domain - see the update to my answer.